# handshake_failure connecting Java client through SSL to Tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, https

```
private void connect(HttpsURLConnection uc) throws IOException {
    uc.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String host, SSLSession sess) {
            return true;
        }
    });

    uc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    uc.setReadTimeout(15 * 1000); // 15 seconds
    uc.connect();
}
```

It is failing on the ClientHello:

```
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
main, setSoTimeout(15000) called
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1461489945 bytes = { 239, 82, 110, 194, 165, 173, 168, 22, 133, 76, 38, 213, 207, 244, 9, 221, 112, 233, 210, 113, 109, 219, 5, 76, 66, 199, 195, 132 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 75
0000: 01 00 00 47 03 01 57 1D   91 19 EF 52 6E C2 A5 AD  ...G..W....Rn...
0010: A8 16 85 4C 26 D5 CF F4   09 DD 70 E9 D2 71 6D DB  ...L&.....p..qm.
0020: 05 4C 42 C7 C3 84 00 00   20 00 04 00 05 00 2F 00  .LB..... ...../.
0030: 33 00 32 00 0A 00 16 00   13 00 09 00 15 00 12 00  3.2.............
0040: 03 00 08 00 14 00 11 00   FF 01 00                 ...........
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 75
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 101
0000: 01 03 01 00 3C 00 00 00   20 00 00 04 01 00 80 00  ....<... .......
0010: 00 05 00 00 2F 00 00 33   00 00 32 00 00 0A 07 00  ..../..3..2.....
0020: C0 00 00 16 00 00 13 00   00 09 06 00 40 00 00 15  ............@...
0030: 00 00 12 00 00 03 02 00   80 00 00 08 00 00 14 00  ................
0040: 00 11 00 00 FF 57 1D 91   19 EF 52 6E C2 A5 AD A8  .....W....Rn....
0050: 16 85 4C 26 D5 CF F4 09   DD 70 E9 D2 71 6D DB 05  ..L&.....p..qm..
0060: 4C 42 C7 C3 84                                     LB...
main, WRITE: SSLv2 client hello message, length = 101
[Raw write]: length = 103
0000: 80 65 01 03 01 00 3C 00   00 00 20 00 00 04 01 00  .e....<... .....
0010: 80 00 00 05 00 00 2F 00   00 33 00 00 32 00 00 0A  ....../..3..2...
0020: 07 00 C0 00 00 16 00 00   13 00 00 09 06 00 40 00  ..............@.
0030: 00 15 00 00 12 00 00 03   02 00 80 00 00 08 00 00  ................
0040: 14 00 00 11 00 00 FF 57   1D 91 19 EF 52 6E C2 A5  .......W....Rn..
0050: AD A8 16 85 4C 26 D5 CF   F4 09 DD 70 E9 D2 71 6D  ....L&.....p..qm
0060: DB 05 4C 42 C7 C3 84                               ..LB...
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 03 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 28                                              .(
main, READ: Unknown-3.3 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.axa.openam.OpenAM_RESTCalls.connect(OpenAM_RESTCalls.java:72)
    at com.axa.openam.OpenAM_RESTCalls.amRestAuthN(OpenAM_RESTCalls.java:91)
    at com.axa.openam.Test.main(Test.java:16)
```

The client runs on Java jre6. The Tomcat server runs on Java jdk1.8.0_11.

The HTTPS configuration in the Tomcat server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" keystoreFile="/export/home/oblxuser/Wes/keystore.jks" keystorePass="changeit" keyAlias="root"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA" URIEncoding="UTF-8" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

I've tried a bunch of things. My suspicion is there is an incompatibility somewhere, but I need the client to run on Java 1.6 and similar deal with the server running on 1.8.

On the server side, keystore.jks was generated by Java jre6 version of keytool in my attempt to make this work for the client.

My suspicion is there is an incompatibility somewhere, be it the client's Java version not be compatible with the Tomcat server's Java version, or the Tomcat server's Java version not be compatible with the keystore's Java version, or what have you. I've tried a bunch of different stuff but exact same result every time.

I don't have a lot of room for changing the versions of the client or the tomcat server, but if that is the cause I would appreciate it being pointed out (and any workaround solutions of course).

Comment: Since the alert is generated by the server as a response to the ClientHello you better look at the server side for information why the server did not like the client.

Comment: I suspect the issue may be that your ciphers selection does not result in a matching client cipher suite. Try removing the ciphers property in Tomcat to see if you see the issue with default ciphers. If it does, consider adding that cipher to you selected list.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich nothing appears to be getting logged to catalina.out. I set the logging level to 'FINEST'

Comment: @Anand Bhat Removed the ciphers property, no luck